# time averaged data in R

Tags: r, average

I am given a dataset of 10 hour length (36.000 time points, 1 second=1 time point). For my further analysis I am supposed to use 10min averaged data which would equal 600 time points. 
So do I understand this right that I have to take the average of the first 600 time points and thats my new time point and then of the next 600 and so on? Which means I end up with a time series of length 60.

How do I do that with R? I thought

```
xF<-filter(x, 600, sides = 2)
```

would be the required function but it just changes the values on the y axis.

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Otherwise it is hard to help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is ordered, you could just create a grouping variable and use `tapply`:

```
# simulate data
x <- rnorm(36000)
# create a group variable
group <- factor(rep(1:(36000/600),each=600))
# compute mean for each slice of 600 data point
mean_by_10min <- tapply(x,group,mean)
```

Comment: This code does exactly what I wanted. I am just wondering when I am asked to use 10min averaged data. Do they want me to use the procedure you described or do they in fact mean the moving average?

Comment: I cannot answer this, you will have to ask whoever has been asking you to do this

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you without having your data 
However, the command looks most likely like

```
aggregate(iris$Petal.Length,by=list(iris$Petal.Width%/%0.5),mean)
```

where you need to replace `iris$Petal.Length` by your values, `iris$Petal.Width` by the timestamps and `0.5` by `600`

Filtering doesn't aggregate your data as I understand your question, hence, you would end up with as many time points.